# Window text selection in a contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

the text selection in a contenteditable causing me big problems...

I'm tryin to get begin and end selection point in the same way of this code part :

http://jsfiddle.net/TjXEG/1/

(Because in the contenteditable, there is differents tags and i need to reselect after a loss of focus the visible selected text (text node ?)

I'm really lost with that, someone know a tutorial or another thing to understand the selection in a web browser ?

Thanks,
Yeppao

Answer (score 2):

Because I only use Chrome, I chopped off the `else` since it doesn't apply. So here's the Chrome solution:

```
Non-editable text. Editable is below:
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">Hello, some <b>bold</b> and <i>italic and <b>bold</b></i> text</div>
<div id="caretPos"></div>
<div id="caretPost"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var begin = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        begin = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
    return "Selection start: " + begin + "<br>Selection end: " + end;
}

function showCaretPos() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test");
    var caretPosEl = document.getElementById("caretPos");
    caretPosEl.innerHTML =  getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(el);
}

document.body.onkeyup = showCaretPos;
document.body.onmouseup = showCaretPos;
</script>
```

Once you understand it, the logic is pretty simple. There is a start and end container. If it is plain text: they will be the same; however, HTML tags fragment the sentence and will make start contain a portion and end contain a different portion.

If you use `setStart()` where I'm using `setEnd()` and reverse the parameters as well, it'll be the same as reversing the index (i.e. the end will be 0 instead of the beginning).

So in order to fetch the beginning, you still use `setEnd()`, except with the start parameters.